# Android: oncreateoptionsmenu not called with asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, options-menu

I have created an application having tab activity which in turn has 5 different list activities in which the options menu is there. Till now it was working fine but since i've added asyncTask the **Options Menu** does not work at first instance but when i switch the tabs and come back to my first tab then only the options menu opens on click.

**Code**

```
public class TopNewsActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "Infra";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
}

public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TopNewsGroup.group);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... paths) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getTopNewsXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Number of Results: " + numResults);
        if ((numResults <= 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "No Result Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            mylist.add(map);
        }
        return mylist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(TopNewsActivity.this, result, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title" }, new int[] { R.id.item_title });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        final ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, final int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(TopNewsActivity.this, NewsDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
                i.putExtra("title", o.get("title"));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                View v = TopNewsGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ShowNews", i).getDecorView();

                // Again, replace the view
                TopNewsGroup.group.setContentView(v);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.refresh:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TopNewsGroup.class));
                return true;

        case R.id.search:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                return true;

        case R.id.info:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TopNewsGroup.class));
                return true;

        case R.id.exit:
                finish();
                return true;
    }
  return false;
}

}
```

Please help.

Comment: please share the source of your `AsyncTask` implementation and the snippet calling it, to have a better understanding of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @rekaszeru : i've added the code, please have a look

Comment: I've even tried your code, because nothing seamed wrong (except the progress dialog instantiation (I've changed that to `new ProgressDialog(TopNewsActivity.this);`, it works fine. But I also removed/changed the parts where you reference this `TopNewsGroup`, since I have no idea what that is, or what its `group` member/inner class is. The options menu shows up on each tab. So your problem might in that `TopNewsGroup` class. Could you tell me what the last two lines in your `onItemClick` method are supposed to do? Are you trying to start a new activity, or to change the selected tab? thank you!

Comment: @rekaszeru: i use 'ActivityGroup' so i can open the onClick link in the same tab. This 'TopNewsGroup' extends the ActivityGroup. As for last two lines in the onItemClick, yes i'm starting a new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i use ActivityGroup i needed to override the following functions to display the optionsmenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return this.getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return this.getCurrentActivity().onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```